# linear transformation preserving linear independency/dependency

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation.

(1) First, we know that any linear transformation is linearly dependency preserving, namely for every $S\subseteq V$, if $S$ is **L.D.**(linearly dependent), then $T(S)$ is **L.D.**. This property has nothing to do with $T$'s being injective or surjective.

(2) If $T$ is one-to-one, then I can prove that $T$ is linear independency preserving, namely for all set $S\subseteq V$, if $S$ is **L.I.**(linearly independent), then $T(S)$ is **L.I.** However, is a general transformation linear independency preserving? If not, is there a counterexample?

(3) Does the preimage operation $T^{-1}$(this is not the inverse) preserve something? Or under what hypothesis it perserve something? Is there a intuitive way to think it fast?

Answer (score 1):

A general transformation doesn't preserve linear indipendency. The statement is true if and only if the transformation is bijective. We will now show a counterexample.

**Counterexample:**

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ be a basis of this space. As it is a basis, it clearly is linearly independent. We want to find a transformation $T$ such that $T(V)$ is not linearly independent. But this is simple:

$T(v_1)=v_1, \quad T(v_2)=v_2 \quad T(v_3)=v_1+v_2$

As this transformation is defined on a basis, it is defined on the entire space. We have that $T(V)=Span(v_1,v_2,v_1+v_2)=Span(v_1,v_2)$ so a space of dimension three is sent into a two-dimensional space, which implies thesis.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any preserving properties about preimage?

Comment: If $T$ is one-to-one the preimage is the inverse. Otherwise I don't remind any particular properties.

Comment: If $T$ is one-to-one but not onto, then the inverse does not exist right?

Comment: Oh damn, I wanted to say bijective.

Comment: Can we give some counterexample that some set $S$ is L.I. in the codomain(or the range) of $T$, while $T^{-1}(S)$ is L.D., and some set $S'$ is L.D. while $T^{-1}(S')$ is L.I.? The hardest part is to give the counterexample I think.